# Finding Solutions of Equations in $\mathbb{Z}_5$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

This one should be easy. Just want to make sure I'm doing the right thing.

Find the solution of the following equations in $\mathbb{Z}_5$:

a) $x + 4 = 0$

b) $3x = 1$

Answer (score 2):

For (a) you just rearrange and work out what the number on the right-hand side is congruent to modulo $5$.

For (b) you find a number $x$ such that $3x$ leaves a remainder of $1$ when you divide it by $5$.

What have you tried? I'm reluctant to give more details until I see some of your working.